# Why Spec R is quasi-compact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand this [proof](http://planetmath.org/proofthatoperatornamespecrisquasicompact)

The only thing I didn't understand is why there exists a finite subset $L$ such that $1_R=\sum_{l\in L}i_l$.

It should be a silly doubt, I'm sure I'm forgetting something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The point is that for $\{I_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ a set of ideals, the ideal

$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} I_\lambda$

is the set of all *finite* sums $i_1+\ldots+i_n$ where each element lies in some $I_\lambda$. We don't include infinite sums because you can't make sense of an infinite sum in arbitrary ring. Thus, since $1\in \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} I_\lambda$, it must be expressible as a finite sum of elements, and so we can take just finitely many of the $I_\lambda$.